# Is there any way to get back the committed changes before a git revert?

Tags: git

I accidently performed a git revert so that I could change a spelling mistake in the immediate previous commit message

```
$ git commit -m "fix: pagination for tag, auhtor pages"
[dev 389531c] fix: pagination for tag, auhtor pages
10 files changed, 398 insertions(+), 64 deletions(-)
...
```

```
$ git revert 389531c
```

I have lost all my changes and want to get them back. I have tried `git reset 389531c` and `git cherry-pick 389531c` but I am not getting my committed changes back and digging myself more into reset. Is there any way to get them back? I am not familiar with "advanced" git commands.

What I want is to get the changes I committed in HEAD@{4}.Here is my git reflog> Thank you.

```
$ git reflog
389531c (HEAD -> dev) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to 389531c
389531c (HEAD -> dev) HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to 389531c
389531c (HEAD -> dev) HEAD@{2}: reset: moving to HEAD@{1}
e7d8df9 HEAD@{3}: revert: Revert "fix: pagination for tag, auhtor pages"
389531c (HEAD -> dev) HEAD@{4}: commit: fix: pagination for tag, auhtor pages
f4c0fb3 (origin/main, origin/HEAD, main) HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from main to dev
```

Comment: Well, I'm also curious to know if it is possible. But for your future reference, you should have used `git commit --amend` to fix the commit message

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado Turns out it was possible as @TTT answered. Yes I will keep in mind about `--amend` flag in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:** Add `--hard` to your reset command.

**Reason:** The command `git reset 389531c` defaults to `--mixed` which means your reverted changes will be pending and still present in your local directory. When you do `--hard` it will also delete those reverted changes.  Another thing you can do is undo your pending changes after a mixed reset.

**Side Note:** As Leonardo Alves Machado pointed out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69167762/is-there-any-way-to-get-back-the-committed-changes-before-a-git-revert/69167827#comment122249879_69167762), a simple way to fix the spelling error (which you can still do after the hard reset) is to make your minor tweak and amend your existing commit (`git commit --amend`).

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I have learnt something of value.

Comment: @dEBAM Happy to help. Learning something of value is why we're all here!